# Livewire and CSS(After adding a new div, class select2 is deleted)

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-livewire

After adding a new div, select2 class is deleted.
I have a form with wire:submit.prevent="sendMessage"

```
 <form wire:submit.prevent="sendMessage" method="POST">
```

The form has a select2 and it works perfectly, except one moment, when I click on a button. A page does not reload, because of wire:submit.prevent. And when message is sent, I add a new div.

```
        @if($sent)
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                A message was sent successfully
            </div>
            <div wire:poll="reuse"></div>
        @endif
```

I checked this code without new div and it works great, however it does not matter which element, when I just try to add something new, class select2 is deleted.

Also I have added `wire:ignore`, and in this case it doesn't work

```
         <div wire:ignore>
                    <select wire:model="type" name="type[]" class="select2" multiple>
                        <option value=""></option>

                        @foreach($types as $type)
                            <option value="{{ $type->id }}">{{ $type->title }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: You'll need to add `wire:ignore`, see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#ignoring-dom-changes

Comment: @Qirel unfortunately, I have done it. And it works in some part of code, however in this case it does not work

Comment: Ok, then I can't say what's wrong without seeing your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a lot of different methods, and only one works perfectly. I added an ID to the  where select is. Now it looks like

```
<div wire:ignore id="select2">
                <select wire:model="type" name="type[]" class="select2" multiple>
                    <option value=""></option>

                    @foreach($types as $type)
                        <option value="{{ $type->id }}">{{ $type->title }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```